# What is the subnet (network and CIDR) for "half" of the IPv4 address space?

Tags: networking, subnet, cidr

What is the subnet (network and CIDR) for "half" of the IPv4 address space? I do not mind if this includes (it inevitable will) private/reserved IP subnets.
To put it even more in context: the subnet/CIDR for the whole IPv4 range is 0.0.0.0/0

Comment: And to clarify, the first half will do ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two ranges 0.0.0.0/1 and 128.0.0.0/1 cover the whole IPv4 space.
CIDR format is a.b.c.d/x where a, b, c and d are the decimal representation of the 4 bytes in the IPv4 address and x is the length of the subnet mask.

To divide the whole range

00000000.00000000.00000000.00000000 to 11111111.11111111.11111111.11111111

in two parts you just consider the ranges

00000000.00000000.00000000.00000000 to 01111111.11111111.11111111.11111111
+
10000000.00000000.00000000.00000000 to 11111111.11111111.11111111.11111111

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for that. I figured out the first part (the address / network) but wasn't sure about the netmask/CIDR.

Answer (score 0):

there are 32 bits in an ipv4 address. All CIDR(classless Interdomain Routing) does is count the number of bits that are ones in sub net mask in the format /32 = 32 1's. Also called running ones from left to right. For 0.0.0.0/0 the cidr is /0 bc the subnet has 0 running ones in it. 
Ex: 192.16.0.0 /16 = subnet mask 255.255.0.0 because there are 16 running one from left to right 11111111.11111111.00000000.00000000 
In binary 8 ones = 255
Similarly, this concept is used for calculating VLSM(Variable length subnet masking)
Ex.
172.30.64.1 /18 = subnet mask 255.255.192.0
11111111.11111111.11000000.00000000 bc /18 means there are 18 running ones in the subnet mask. The third octet is 192 bc 11000000 in decimal is 128+64=192.
Hope this helps! -j